# Groovy - check if param is a function

Tags: function, groovy, parameters, typechecking

In JavaScript, this is how I check if a function parameter is a function:

```
function foo ( p ) {
    if ( typeof p === 'function' ) {
        p();
    }
    // ....
}
```

How can I do the same in Groovy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Groovy makes [closures](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) a first-class citizen. Each closure extends abstract class [`groovy.lang.Closure<V>`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html) and in case of undefined argument type you can use `instanceof` to check if parameter that was passed to a method is a closure. Something like that:

```
def closure = {
    println "Hello!"
}

def foo(p) {
    if (p instanceof Closure) {
        p()
    }
}

foo(closure)
```

Running this script generates output:

```
Hello!
```

#### Using concrete parameter type

Groovy allows you (and it's worth doing actually) to define a type of a method parameter. Instead of checking if `p` was a closure, you can require that caller passes a closure. Consider following example:

```
def closure = {
    println "Hello!"
}

def foo2(Closure cl) {
    cl()
}

foo2(closure)
foo2("I'm not a closure")
```

First call will do what closure does (prints "Hello!"), but second call will throw an exception:

```
Hello!
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: test.foo2() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [I'm not a closure]
Possible solutions: foo2(groovy.lang.Closure), foo(java.lang.Object), find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), run()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: test.foo2() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [I'm not a closure]
Possible solutions: foo2(groovy.lang.Closure), foo(java.lang.Object), find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), run()
    at test.run(test.groovy:18)
```

It's always a good practice to make your code type-safe, so you don't have to worry if a value passed as a parameter is a type you expect.

Comment: I think you could as well go for `Runnable`

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that. `Closure<V>` returns `V`, so if we expect something in return from the function/closure, then using `Runnable` won't fit.

Comment: I mean, that `instance of Runnable` and then `p.run()` might even be more generic.  But yeah, no return value from that.

Answer (score 5):

In Groovy, you'd want to check if `p` is an `instanceof` a `Closure`

```
def foo(p) {
    if (p instanceof Closure) {
        p()
    } else {
        println "p is $p and not a Closure"
    }
}

foo { -> println "I'm a closure" }
foo('tim')
```

Outputs:

```
I'm a closure
p is tim and not a Closure
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def eval = {o->([o].grep(Closure).find()?:{o})()}

println eval('foo')
println eval({->'bar'})
println eval{'baz'}
```